# CBCMac (DESede) implementation in objective c

Tags: objective-c, encryption, cryptography, des

Has any one implemented CBC Mac (DESede) in Objective c? Could you show sample code or explain how to correct my code?

Here is my effort so far....

```
-(void)tryMac
{
unsigned char blockCount;

unsigned char key[16] = "\x1\x2\x3\x4\x5\x6\x7\x8\x9\x0\x1\x2\x3\x4\x5\x6";
unsigned char data[16] = "\x54\x68\x69\x73\x69\x73\x6d\x79\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67\x0\x0";

DES_cblock *desKey1 = (DES_cblock* ) key;
DES_cblock *desKey2 = (DES_cblock* ) key;


unsigned char *iv = (unsigned char *) malloc(8);
memset(iv, 0x0, 8);
DES_set_odd_parity(desKey1);
DES_set_odd_parity(desKey2);
DES_key_schedule schedule1;
DES_key_schedule schedule2;
DES_set_key_checked(desKey1, &schedule1);
DES_set_key_checked(desKey2, &schedule2);


int len = sizeof(data);
blockCount = len / 4;
int lastBlock = 0;
for(unsigned char i = 0; i < blockCount; i++)
{
    int bufferLen  = sizeof(data)/blockCount;
    unsigned char buffer[bufferLen];
    memccpy(buffer, data, lastBlock, bufferLen);
    lastBlock = (i + 1) * bufferLen;

    unsigned char *result = (unsigned char *) malloc(4);

    if (lastBlock == len)
    {
        DES_ede2_cbc_encrypt(buffer, result, bufferLen, &schedule1, &schedule2, (DES_cblock *) iv, DES_ENCRYPT);

        NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)result length:4];
        NSString *encryptedString = [self stringWithHexFromData:encryptedData];
        NSLog(@"Encrypted Block %@",encryptedString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just bikeshedding, but CBC-MAC is not secure *if* the plain text is not a multiple of the cipher's block size. Better choices would be an HMAC, CMAC (CMAC is CBC-MAC done right), or one of the Authenticated Encryption modes like CCM or GCM.

Comment: @jww CBC-MAC is already implemented on the server...I have no control over that..

Comment: [Network Security with OpenSSL](http://www.amazon.com/dp/059600270X) provides the source code. Check Section 7.3.1.1 CBC-MAC, pp. 173-175. The book gives you the code for `CBCMAC_Init`, `CBCMAC_Update`, `CBCMAC_Final` and `CBCMAC`. You can find it online with some searching.